# PHP.ini whats the variable which relaxes the need for $ with variables?

Tags: php

I'm trying to mirror my ISPs server and he has this set to strict, where you need to specify $

And I don't

What is it ?

EDIT

This works on my test server

`if (nothingfound != "TRUE") {`

but doesn't on the live server

`if ($nothingfound != "TRUE") {`

Both are running PHP 5.2.17 (no I can't upgrade to 5.3 at the moment)

Comment: Can you give an example? I have never seen PHP code that does not use `$` for indicating variables (and that works ;)).

Comment: This is probably an issue with the error reporting. PHP variables are never valid without `$` prefix.

Comment: In the first code you compare constant (undefined) with string; in the second - variable with string.

Comment: put `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporing(E_ALL);` right before that 2 cases.

Comment: Whats this for `variables_order = "GPCS"` ?. My ISP said there was a variable but he wasn't sure. @zerkms, but why would that cause a difference between servers ?

Comment: LOL you have mixed up EVERYTHING! you are using a constant instead of a variable, AND a string ("TRUE") instead of constant! You desperately need to read some manual pages. Try to use === operator instead of ==. You will be surprised even more

Comment: Your code is just wrong. And it gave you "correct" results by chance. Where do you define `$nothingfound`?

Comment: @Jules: http://ideone.com/qOVC4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (nothingfound != "TRUE") {
```

actually only works because PHP will look for a constant called `nothingfound` and if it doesn't find one, it'll treat the token as the literal string `'nothingfound'`. Depending on your `error_reporting` PHP will issue a notice such as

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant nothingfound - assumed 'nothingfound' in ...
```

So to stick with your example

```
if (nothingfound != "TRUE") {
```

works, but

```
if (nothingfound == "TRUE") {
```

will never work (unless you have a constant `nothingfound` defined that contains the string `"TRUE"`).